# Android override UnderlineSpan() to overline instead of underline

Tags: android, customization, spannablestring, spannable, strikethrough

I am new to Android, I have this piece of code that underlines a SpannableString. I want to modify the object UnderlineSpan() so that it overlines the Spannablestring instead of underlining it. So basically I want it to make the line over the string and not under it. How can I accomplish this? Is there any other way to do this? Thanks

```
spannableString=new SpannableString(s);
            spannableString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(),1,spannableString.length(),0);
```

Comment: You can't.  Instead, create a new spannable class and have it overline when it draws

Comment: You are right, I should've worded the question a bit differently, I meant create a new class that extends UnderlineSpan(), I did find this article http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/
which shows how to use an abstract class called ReplacementSpan and I tried it out. It does overline but it doesn't write the text below the overlined span. 
Is there any way to underline whitespace in a spannable? That way I can underline the whitespace and add a newline character so it will look like I am overlining the text.